# Loadbalancing with Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, load-balancing, port-forwarding

I am looking to create a load balancing server. Essentially here is what I want to do,

I have a public ip address, lets say 1.1.1.1 I have a second public ip address, lets say 2.2.2.2

Here is what I want to happen. I have a website www.f.com point to 1.1.1.1 via an A record. I want that ubuntu server to forward traffic appropriately.

Port 80 traffic is forwarded to 2.2.2.2 on port 60,000 and port 60,001 Port 443 traffic is forwaded to 2.2.2.2 on port 60,010 and port 60,011 Port 25 traffic is forwared to 2.2.2.2 on port 60,020 and port 60,021

I think you probably understand what I am thinking. The port forwarding from port to port is more important then being able to load balance.

I look forward to some responses. Both server 1.1.1.1 and 2.2.2.2 are both running Ubuntu 12.04 server edition.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [haproxy](http://haproxy.1wt.eu/). The setup you describe would be trivially easy to set up.

Here's a (very simple) example for your port 80:

```
global
    daemon
    maxconn 256

defaults
    mode http
    timeout connect 5000ms
    timeout client 50000ms
    timeout server 50000ms

frontend http-in
    bind *:80
    default_backend port80

backend port80
    server s1 2.2.2.2:60000 maxconn 32
    server s2 2.2.2.2:60001 maxconn 32
```

Comment: Any examples? I have never used haproxy

Comment: Example posted. There is very good documentation on the haproxy page.